# Frequency table made on subset of data includes zero values that were filtered out

Tags: r

I have a data table which for the purposes of the question can be simplified to this:

```
eg.ID <- rep(LETTERS[1:26], length.out=30)
eg.filter <- rep(0:1, length.out=30)
eg.df <- data.frame(eg.ID, eg.filter)
```

Which gives:

```
> eg.df
   eg.ID eg.filter
1      A         0
2      B         1
3      C         0
4      D         1
...    ...       ...
23     W         0
24     X         1
25     Y         0
26     Z         1
27     A         0
28     B         1
29     C         0
30     D         1
```

I want to use the eg.filter column to ignore all the rows where the value is 0, and then to count how many times each eg.ID occurs:

```
eg.df[eg.df$eg.filter==1,]$eg.ID
table(eg.df[eg.df$eg.filter==1,]$eg.ID)
```

The initial output I get is as expected:

```
> eg.df[eg.df$eg.filter==1,]$eg.ID
 [1] B D F H J L N P R T V X Z B D
Levels: A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

Just the letters where eg.filter==1.

However, I then run table()

```
> table(eg.df[eg.df$eg.filter==1,]$eg.ID)
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 
0 2 0 2 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

And all the letters where e.g.filter==0 reappear (albeit with a correct count of 0). I don't want them.

I suspect I've made a fundamental misunderstanding of the [] operator, but despite trawling the manual can't work out what it is. Help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have to drop the unused levels of the factor if you don't want the values 0.

Comment: Thanks. 
table(droplevels(eg.df[eg.df$eg.filter==1,]$eg.ID))
Gets me the expected result. 

Is there a way to make [] drop unused levels automatically? I'd already been on the manual page for droplevels but ended up not trying it after attempting:
eg.df[eg.df$eg.filter==1,,drop=TRUE]$eg.ID
and not getting the expected result!

Comment: @Dan : In `eg.df[eg.df$eg.filter==1, , drop=TRUE]$eg.ID` you are using `"[.data.frame"` and not `"[.factor"` so "drop = TRUE" refers to the "drop" argument when subsetting a "data.frame". You need to use either `eg.df$eg.ID[eg.df$eg.filter==1, drop = TRUE]` or `eg.df[eg.df$eg.filter==1, ]$eg.ID[drop = TRUE]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `droplevels` to remove the unused levels in the 'eg.ID' column.

```
table(droplevels(eg.df[eg.df$eg.filter>0,]))
#        eg.filter
#eg.ID 1
#    B 2
#    D 2
#    F 1
#    H 1
#    J 1
#    L 1
#    N 1
#    P 1
#    R 1
#    T 1
#    V 1
#    X 1
#    Z 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just subset it, then run `table()`

```
# Sample code -- note stringAsFactors = FALSE
df <- data.frame(id = rep(LETTERS[1:26], length.out=30), filter = rep(0:1, length.out=30), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

table(df[df$filter > 0, ])
```

Output:

```
 > table(df[df$filter > 0, ])
  filter
id  1
  B 2
  D 2
  F 1
  H 1
  J 1
  L 1
  N 1
  P 1
  R 1
  T 1
  V 1
  X 1
  Z 1
```